# Best way to phrase sentence

Tags: sentence

I'm developing a website, working on the various text which will be shown to the user.

I currently have this sentence:

> Would you like us to remember you next time you visit?

I feel this may be too much 'write what you speak' - is this the correct way to phrase it, or is there a better way?

Comment: Are you saying that spoken English is incorrect? And what context are we talking about? Ucla.edu? Twitch.tv? CIA.gov? Brazzers.com? Royal.gov.uk? Microsoft,com? Which part of microsoft.com? And what is your motivation for torturing users with complete  sentences instead of a checkbox that says "remember me"? Please elaborate.

Comment: Not spoken English in general... just my own! For example, somebody pointed out that it should maybe say "Would you like us to remember you **the** next time you visit?". Another has said "Would you like us to remember you**r details** next time you visit?" My question was to see what the most appropriate way of explaining the functionality was. The complete sentence is being given for accessibility - something that is beyond the scope of my question

Answer (score 2):

Most websites will just pose the question `remember me?` to the user. This is fairly common these days and as such most users will understand what it means. Alternatively, you could use `stay logged in?`